# Android Get TextView Content That Was Scrolled Out And That Is Scrolled In In ScrollView

Tags: android, textview, android-scrollview

I am trying to get textview content that was scrolled out and that the content that is scrolled in a scrollview. I tried using the observablescrollview to track onScroll, but the method is called multiple times and i don't know which y value to use. Here is the observable scrollview method:

```
scrollView.setOnScrollListener(new ObservableScrollView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollChanged(ObservableScrollView scrollView, int x, int y, int oldX, int oldY) {
            Log.i("Scroll", "y: " + y);
        }

        @Override
        public void onEndScroll(ObservableScrollView scrollView) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

there must be a method in variable scrollview which is a parameter like get current position. Try to use it if exists in methods on start and end to get the difference